# How to position absolute children inside relative parent, when relative parent does not have height and width?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to fit position:absolute div's inside position:relative parent. In my case position:absolute div's are generated dynamically. I wanted to expand position:relative div based on the position:absolute div's.

Here is the example,

```css
#one {
  position:relative;
  background-color: pink;
}

#two {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left: 50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#three {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left: 50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#four {
  position:relative;
  background-color: violet;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">First</div>
  <div id="three">Second</div>
</div>
<div id="four">Third</div>
```

In the above example, the div#one has no height and width, so the div#four overlaps div#two. I want div#four should stick after div#three.

I searched for an answer and I couldn't get any answer from the web.
Can anyone please answer this!

Comment: Why do you need to use position:absolute ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
#one {
  background-color: pink;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#two {
  background-color: green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#three {
  background-color: yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#four {
  background-color: violet;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">First</div>
  <div id="three">Second</div>
</div>
<div id="four">Third</div>
```

If that's the case you don't need the absolute positioning for `#two` and `#three`. Just let them flow in `static` (default position). If you need them to be 50px left from the start of `#one` you could add a padding-left on `#one`, or a margin-left on both `#two` and `#three`, or put those on position relative, instead of absolute, and keep the `left: 50px;`

In fact, you can see that I haven't changed any `position` at all. The default `static` does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: Hi Jordi, thanks for your quick reply. Here I am looking for the answer to align position: absolute div's inside position: relative div. I know and I see your answer works! but it is not what I am looking for. Thank again!

Comment: Well, in that case, you're experiencing the classic collapsing container problem I'd suggest you to read about floating/absolute elements and clearfix hack. But, again, I think you're overkilling it.If you have a problem to solve go for the easiest solution that works. UX/UI will say to you: I want it to look and behave like this BUT shouldn't say I want it with absolute positioned divs. In this specific case, you're trying to get the default behaviour in a complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

Add top and left values to your fourth relatively positioned object.

```css
#one {
  position:relative;
  background-color: pink;
}

#two {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left: 50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#three {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left: 50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#four {
  position:relative;
  background-color: violet;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  top:200px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">First</div>
  <div id="three">Second</div>
</div>
<div id="four">Third</div>
```

Comment: Hi Vineeta, thanks for your reply. Actually I am trying to align div#four below without adding top or left position. Is there any possibility to do that?